# In my "FAQ" section, make <dt> look like an <a> with jquery

Tags: jquery

My stylesheet has two definitions:

```
bodytext a { border-bottom-color: #9aa1ae; border-bottom-width: 1px; 
border-bottom-style: solid; color: #00589f; }
bodytext a:hover { border-bottom-color: #0d1117; border-bottom-width: 1px; 
border-bottom-style: solid; color: #0d1117; }
```

and my page has an FAQ section, like so

```
<dl class='faq'>
  <dt>Question 1</dt>
  <dd>Answer 1</dd>
  <dt>Question 2</dd>
  <dd>Answer 1</dd>
</dl>
```

I wrote a simple jquery to expand/contract the FAQ, as follows:

```
$('dl.faq dd').hide();
$('dl.faq dt').click(function(){
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

so that if javascript is off, the FAQ is still readable.

However, right now, I'm worried that my readers aren't clicking the questions to expand them.  I'd like the `dt`s to look like `a`s so they look clickable, and preferably have the `a` and `a:hover` definitions appear only once in my stylesheet.  How do I do this in jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you find where you define the `a` and change like so in the CSS

```
a,
dl.faq dt {
   color: blue;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

You could also put a unique id on every answer, and actually use a link to it, for example

```
<dl class='faq'>
  <dt><a href="#question-1">Question 1</a></dt>
  <dd id="question-1">Answer 1</dd>
  <dt>Question 2</dd>
  <dd>Answer 1</dd>
</dl>
```

That way, you could also link people to individual questions / answers. It will also jump their browser viewport to the answer when clicked.

Comment: because I don't want the page to jump up and down when a javascript-enabled user expands or contracts the questions.  I can and do link people to individual questions / answers by giving each `dt` an id.

I'd just like my `dt`s look like `a`s, not behave like them, and only for javascript-enabled readers. Thanks.

Comment: @Anna Simply add an event for JavaScript to those links and use `preventDefault()` or `return false`. This will stop the usual browser behaviour.

Comment: Alex, I'd really like to code the questions as plain `dt`s, not as `a`s.  If they were `a`s, then the page will still jump up and down with javascript-disabled readers. Unnecessarily, I should add.  Thanks.

Comment: @Anna You can stop that behaviour with JavaScript. Anyway, why can't your `a` selector in your CSS also select the `dt` element as well? You will need to explicitly add `cursor: pointer` as well to get the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my stylesheet to this:

```
bodytext a, .a-like { border-bottom-color: #9aa1ae; border-bottom-width: 1px; 
border-bottom-style: solid; color: #00589f; }
bodytext a:hover, .a-like:hover { border-bottom-color: #0d1117; border-bottom-width: 1px; 
border-bottom-style: solid; color: #0d1117; }
```

Since `dt` is a block-level tag and `a` is an inline tag, I changed my HTML so it won't look insane:

```
<dl class='faq'>
    <dt><span>Question 1</span></dt>
    <dd>Answer 1</dd>
    <dt><span>Question 2</span></dd>
    <dd>Answer 1</dd>
</dl>
```

Finally, I changed my javascript to this

```
$('dl.faq dd').hide();
$('dl.faq dt span').addClass('a-like');
$('dl.faq dt').css("cursor", "pointer");
$('dl.faq dt').click(function(){
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
  $(this).children(":first").toggleClass('a-like');
});
```

Thus, when javascript is off, it looks like a Definition list.  When javascript is on, it looks like an interactive FAQ.  Thanks, Alex, for throwing some ideas.